# True and false after return

Tags: java

Что обозначает false или true после оператора return и в каких позициях обозначаются условия false и true

Comment: Тут три вопроса: разберитесь сначала что такое false и true, затем разберитесь что делает return. Если что-то будет непонятно, то уточните что именно. Приведите пример.

Answer (score 3):

`False` - обозначает ложное выражение, как например (3 < 2).
`True` - обозначает истинное выражение, как например (3 > 2).

Использовать эти выражения после оператора `return` можно слудующим образом:

```
public boolean isEmpty(Object[] array) {
   boolean result; // по-умолчанию false
   result = array.length == 0 ? true : false;
   return result;
}
```

Данный метод вернет нам истинное или ложное значение о том, является ли переданный ему массив пустым или нет.

Comment: Не показывайте людям этот тернарный оператор, пожалуйста...

Comment: @vp_arth почему?

Comment: Потому что `return array.length == 0;`, вот почему